# Reusable typed react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I want to know whether it is possible to create a reusable component ( For example a CRUD Table ) that can infer types correctly from the outside of the component itself.

Let's bring an example to be more clear.
Let's assume we have a **CRUDtable** component.

```
interface IProps {
  createCall: (data: any) => any;
  tableData: any[];
}

export const CRUDTable = (props: IProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* here goes some JSX */}
      {props.tableData.map((entry, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {/* here we map tableData and each row takes 
                it's own portion and has it's own onClick
                which provides the entry data to listeners
            */}
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

And we use this table in different components with different data.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const createCall = (data) => {
    // do some data fetching
  }

  const tableData = [
    { id: 1, name: 'David', address: 'some address'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Angela', address: 'some address 2'},
    { id: 3, name: 'Arthur', address: 'some address3'},
  ]

  return (
    <CRUDTable 
      tableData={tableData}
      createCall={createCall}
    />
  )
}
```

I want to make this CRUDTable component generic typed.So that it can infer the right types from the outside of the Table through **tableData**. I want to replace **any** with some generic type which can correctly infer the relevant types from outside of the table.

```
<CRUDTable 
  tableData={tableData}
  createCall={createCall}
/>
```

So that whenever we use **CRUDTable** component, it can correctly set types for **createCall**.

I have already tried to add generics but without any result.

```
interface IProps<T> {
  createCall: (data: T) => any;
  tableData: any[];
}

export const CRUDTable = <Data,>(props: IProps<Data>) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* here goes some JSX */}
      {props.tableData.map((entry, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {/* here we map tableData and each row takes 
                it's own portion and has it's own onClick
                which provides the entry data to listeners
            */}
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be should work like this:
ParentComponent

```
import "./styles.css";
import Table from "./Table";

type ItemType = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  address: string;
};

export default function App() {
  const createCall = (data: ItemType) => {
    // do some data fetching
  };

  const tableData: ItemType[] = [
    { id: 1, name: "David", address: "some address" },
    { id: 2, name: "Angela", address: "some address 2" },
    { id: 3, name: "Arthur", address: "some address3" }
  ];

  return <Table tableData={tableData} createCall={createCall} />;
}
```

TableComponent

```
import React from "react";

interface TableProps<T> {
  tableData: T[];
  createCall: (column: T) => void;
}
const Table = <T extends unknown>(
  props: React.PropsWithChildren<TableProps<T>>
) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* here goes some JSX */}
      {props.tableData.map((entry, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {/* here we map tableData and each row takes 
                it's own portion and has it's own onClick
                which provides the entry data to listeners
            */}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

You can see work example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-cannon-k6j97?file=/src/Table.tsx)

**EDIT:**
With React.memo use this way:

```
export default React.memo(Table) as typeof Table
```

Comment: Well, it works , but in my case I use React.memo for CRUDTable.
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-hertz-rxihn?file=/src/App.tsx

Here we can see a ts error on createCall.

Comment: const MemoizedComponent = React.memo(innerComponent) as typeof innerComponent;

Comment: Today is only this way I mentioned in prev comment, you can see full discussion about it here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/37087#issuecomment-656596623

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan I've edited my answer for React.memo

Comment: Yeah, before your answer, I was reading that issue and yes you are right. Unfortunately, the only workaround is to assert the type for the memoized table. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Generics is probably the solution - for every different table, you should create a data type that contains all the fields of its row. If we'll take the example you provided:

```js
interface RowData {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  address: string
}
```

Then you can use that type as the type of your `CRUDTable` component as you did, just use it for `tableData` as well:

```js
tableData: T[];
```

Comment: Actually, it works pretty well, but I have wrapped my Table component with React.memo, and here is the problem. Somehow React.memo doesn't pass the correct types.